# Ionic 3- Hide ion-input while typing

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, formatting

I need to format the output of an ion-input, so I don't want the input field to return what the user is actually typing.
I have a function invoked from ngModelChange and would like to only show the result of that function, which is the variable formatNum inside the ion-label, and hide what the user is actually typing in ion-input.

```
<ion-item no-padding class="rightBorder">
            <ion-label fixed>Phone 1</ion-label>
            <ion-input placeholder="(###) ###-####" [(ngModel)]="customer.phone" (ngModelChange)="formatPhone()"  pattern="[0-9]*"></ion-input>
            <ion-label>{{formatNum}}</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the text  transparent, by using `rgba`

```
input[type="text"] { 
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
     caret-color:black
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, the only issue with that is that it hides the curser with the text.

Comment: Hi I have updated my answer and mark it if it helped you